# Node.js Multiple concurrent request at the same time

Tags: node.js, axios, concurrency, interceptor

Greetting everyone!

I need help with something, currently I'm developing a API in node.js, that make a lot of requests to other apis, and I need to collect the time that each request takes to execute, together with the returned data; I'm using express and an axios instance, and promise.allSettle() inside an asycn function. The problem is that each request is taking more time compare to postman for example and depending of the quantity of request make the times of response increment a lot, I attached a picture that shows the times with different quantities of requests and where it says responseTime is an example of how long the API tells me that just one request took and it's the lowest time that I get:

[image]

And add an example of the code that I'm using to make each request, it's called inside and a map:

```
export const axiosRequest = async ({method, url, body, queryParams, headers}) => {
try {
const axiosClient = axios.create();

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  config.metadata = { startTime: new Date() };
  return config; 
});

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    const endTime = new Date();
    const processingTime = endTime - response.config.metadata.startTime;
    response.config.metadata.processingTime = processingTime;
    return response;
  },
  error => {
    const endTime = new Date();
    const processingTime = endTime - error.config.metadata.startTime;
    error.config.metadata.processingTime = processingTime;
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

const response = await axiosClient({
  method,
  url,
  data: body,
  headers,
  params: queryParams,
});

return response;

} catch (error) {
return Promise.reject(error);
}

};
```